# php make hidden fields tamper proof ?

Tags: php, forms, spoofing

I'm not wanting to use a framework when in this project there is only a single value that needs verifying, I want to make sure however that the method I'm using is reasonably safe and sane!

I have a $secret value set in an include that is outside the web root

the form looks like this ( $salt is a random integer a new one for each form)

```
<form name="deleteform" action="#" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="check" value="<?=sha1($salt.$secret.$songid)?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="songid" value="<?=$songid?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="salt" value="<?=$salt?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete"/>
<input type="submit" value="Delete"/></form>
```

when the form is returned I use the returned values for $salt $songid along with $secret to calculate a new sha1 and compare it to $check

if they are equal I assume that the returned $songid hasn't been tampered with

Comment: Why not just save values in `$_SESSION`? Nothing the browser sends you can be trusted.

Comment: i agree with @NiettheDarkAbsol , never trust data sent from the browser, it is better to use $_SESSION

Comment: You should never use GET for a destructive action. Also, what exactly are you "checking" here to begin with?

Comment: ^^^ $_SESSION is the way to go...

Comment: As an example, all the "security" in the world didn't stop me from hacking my own old Pokémon site to get a Level 500 Shiny Mew :p Ah, my beginning programming years...

Comment: missing the point guys not trusting ANYTHING from the browser unless it is verified as not tampered with, READ where $secret is coming from and what is happening with it - what's to stop anyone spoofing session ID this comes from the browser (I'm sure bouncing from session to session could vandalise data no end)...

Answer (score 0):

Using $_SESSIONS is the way to go. Even if you wanted to still do the tamper proof hidden field idea. To make it tamper proof you'd have to set the value on the server side after hitting submit. You could do this using jQuery's `.preventDefault()`, set the value of the hidden fields at that point, and then continue with the submission. But why do the extra step?

Just use sessions from the get go, eg:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['name'] = value;

echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

Answer (score -1):

$_SESSION is the way to go... the downside of your design is that one can still temper with the form by simply copy/pasting values.

Also, if they figure out what kind of check you are doing, there is absolutely nothing stopping them from putting in their own songid, computing their own sha1 hash and stuffing it into your check field.

General intro to sessions:

```
 session_start();

$_SESSION['songid']=your song id;
```

and you are done... Now the songid value is stored on server, and nothing can tamper with it besides you... unless openSSL breaks again.

Comment: curious to know how they would calculate an sha1 without $secret being available to them?